# Karma junitReporter.outputFile is empty

Tags: jenkins, karma-runner, yeoman-generator-angular

I'm configuring Karma to work with Jenkins CI as described [here](https://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/plus/jenkins.html).

My `junitReporter.outputFile`, `test-results.xml`, is always empty.

Per the docs (linked above) `Please note the test-results.xml files will be written to subdirectories named after the browsers the tests were run in inside the present working directory (and you will need to tell Jenkins where to find them).`

I'm using PhantomJS to run my tests. I do not see any subdirectories named after PhantomJS.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding `karma-junit-reporter` to plugins in my `karma.conf.js` file and everything started working, like so:

```
// Which plugins to enable
plugins: [
  "karma-phantomjs-launcher",
  "karma-jasmine",
  "karma-junit-reporter"
],

// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
singleRun: true,
reporters: ['progress', 'junit'],
// the default configuration
junitReporter: {
  outputDir: 'test', // results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName.xml
  outputFile: 'test-results.xml', // if included, results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName/$outputFile
  suite: '', // suite will become the package name attribute in xml testsuite element
  useBrowserName: true // add browser name to report and classes names
},
```